# How to add turbolinks to a Webview app

Tags: ios, swift, turbolinks

I have made a native swift slide out menu for an iOS Webview application built in swift. I am trying to make the slide out menu links call javascript in the application. The javascript in the application is already set I just need to call it in the iOS app. 
This is the code I have so far

```
func changeViewController(menu: LeftMenu) {
    switch menu {
    case .Main:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.mainViewController, close: true)
    case .Swift:
        webView!.evaluateJavaScript("Turbolinks.visit(‘theurl/clients')", completionHandler: nil)
        break
    case .Java:
        webView!.evaluateJavaScript("Turbolinks.visit(‘theurl/contacts')", completionHandler: nil)
        break
    case .Go:
        webView!.evaluateJavaScript("Turbolinks.visit(‘theurl/tasks')", completionHandler: nil)
        break
    case .NonMenu:
        webView!.evaluateJavaScript("Turbolinks.visit(‘theurl/leads')", completionHandler: nil)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```